# With ASP.NET MVC redirect to login page when session expires

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I want to redirect to login page when session expires. How can I achieve this? If I am doing an AJAX call to a method in controller then if my session expires in that situation also I want to redirect to login page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you could do this by 3 ways:

1. Create a filter to your actions and apply it programming a code in OnActionExecuting (before the action been executed), http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs
2. Create a base class (inheriting from Controller class) and make your controllers inherits from this one. In this class you could overwrite a method called OnActionExecuting, like the filter.
3. Don't use Session for Authentication, you can use Forms authentication and keep it simple to use, look this: http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/02/07/asp-net-mvc-framework-using-forms-authentication.aspx

In my opinion, the solution 3 is better than other. I hope it works for you!

Comment: Solution 3 is wrong.  Using forms authentication the user can still be authenticated via a cookie but have a brand new session.  If your controller does not catch this then you can have exceptions trying to access the Session object which has not been configured by the login page.

Comment: Solution 1 is technically incorrect.  Although a filter, one use derived from `AuthorizeAttribute` and `IAuthorizationFilter` and then override `OnAuthorization` and/or `AuthorizeCore` depending on the situation.  This is the case all the way back to MVC 2.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, could you please suggest a link/example to further clarify. Thanks.

Comment: 3 solutions for a single Problem. Thumps Up :) . And let us know if any more solution you have for this problem ;)

Answer (score 7):

because it's possible to copy the security-cookie of the Forms-Authentication use it to simulate a registered user I use the following attribute to bind the authentication to the current session lifetime.

To make the Attribute work you have to set session["user"] = MyUser on login and call session.abandom() on logout.
I don't know if the redirect works with ajax calls - that's something you have to try.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CheckUserSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        var user = session["User"];

        if (((user == null) && (!session.IsNewSession)) || (session.IsNewSession))
        {
            //send them off to the login page
            var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            var loginUrl = url.Content("~/Account/LogOff");
            session.RemoveAll();
            session.Clear();
            session.Abandon();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The redirect doesn't seem to work for me.  I have an MVC mobile site which seems to mean everything uses AJAX.  Not sure how you get the redirect to work.

Comment: if i apply this attribute to a class, how can i write an invert attribute to apply it to the action? UncheckUserSessionAttribute for example

Comment: I think this is not supported by the MVC framework. As far as I know it will evaluate all filter attributes. I can't imagine a way how to solve your problem. So you have to apply it to every method in your class.

Comment: This seems to run the code but continuw on to executing the original action anyway which in my case causes an error because the whole point is that action expects there to be a user in the session and it isn't there

Comment: Quick note: `if (((user == null) && (!session.IsNewSession)) || (session.IsNewSession))` can simply be re-written as `if (user == null || session.IsNewSession)`

Answer (score 4):

This answers is heavily based on Michaels except it works ;-)

I changed it to take a delegate for checking if the session has ended so it can work in different apps which might have different ways of determining this and also the login page might be different in other apps.  In the Global.asax.cs Application_Start() the code I have in my app is

```
CheckUserSessionAttribute.CheckSessionAlive = session => (session.GetUser() != null);
CheckUserSessionAttribute.LoginUrl = "~/Account/Login";
```

Then the attribute class is as follows

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CheckUserSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public static String LoginUrl { get; set; }
        public delegate bool CheckSessionDelegate(HttpSessionStateBase session);

        public static CheckSessionDelegate CheckSessionAlive;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            if ((CheckSessionAlive == null) || (CheckSessionAlive(session)))
                    return;


            //send them off to the login page
            var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            var loginUrl = url.Content(LoginUrl);
            session.RemoveAll();
            session.Clear();
            session.Abandon();

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, false);
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();

        }
    }
```

From your controller just add the [CheckUserSession] attribute above the class or the individual actions.

Answer (score 1):

Another plausible solution could be found in here:

**[Overriding Controller Methods for session Timeout handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873398/how-to-redirect-to-logon-page-when-session-state-time-out-is-completed-in-asp-ne/19049002#19049002)**