# asp.net mvc redirect to login on session expiry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I am trying to do a simple redirect to login page if session expires in asp.net mvc 4.5. I am trying it as follows.

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Session_OnEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.RedirectToRoute("Default"); //default is route
}
```

but here null exception comes and response object is not found. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091498/with-asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-expires) post but could not figure out as it is pretty broad.

**UPDATE**

I have tried applying filter as follows now it does not crash but also does not redirect to error page.

**SessionTimeoutAttribute**

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SchoolCode"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Views/Shared/Error");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Added Attribute to Controller class

```
[SessionTimeout]
public class MapsController : Controller{}
```

Why doesnt it redirect?

Comment: What do you mean by "response object is not found" ? Did you try putting a `try...catch` around your code to check if any exception thrown?

Comment: as the answer suggests in the post you have linked, use `ActionFilters` and check for `Session` inside it.

Comment: i get An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Response is not available in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my code a little

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SchoolCode"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(
                                                        new { action = "Login", controller = "Account" }));                
            //return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

ignore **Session_OnEnd** code its no use.