# ASP.NET MVC redirect to login page after session expires in AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I just learning ASP.NET MVC and newbie in it so I can't find the solution for some problem. Maybe somebody faced this problem and can give me advice? Thanks for all!

In my project, I use ASP.NET Identity for authorization.
The only problem I faced is how to redirect the user to login page after session expires. If action from controller called not from AJAX it works well, but if action called from AJAX function it crashes. I search for the solution, but everything I found not working for me.
Now my code looks like:

`Startup.cs`

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationContext>(ApplicationContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
                LogoutPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
               
            });
        }
```

`Web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login"  timeout="1" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

Function from JS which calls action:

```
function click(d) {
                //Some logic
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetDataForNode", "Home")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cahe: false,
                        data: { uid: d.id, index: index, nodesUid: nodesUid, request },
                        success: function (results) {
                            //Some logic
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            if (xhr.status === 401) {
                                window.location.href = xhr.Data.LogOnUrl;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    })
            }
```

And in controller I created:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        Error = "NotAuthorized",
                        LogOnUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl
                    },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
                
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

After executed I get this
[image]

Comment: due to *401* status code looks like result is not returned, try using different status code

Comment: `but if action called from AJAX function it crash` Define `crash`.

Comment: @mjwills I mean result that I added in image. As expected when ajax method get error with 401 code it return to login page. But it not works.

Comment: Please, Go through the below link you will get your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091498/with-asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-expires

Comment: @krunalpatel none of the answers in that question really deal with the ajax scenario, despite the mention of it in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Add a life cycle method Application_EndRequest handler to your code in global.asax.cs. Every request will end in this method, This method will allows you to redirect to appropriate action, when your request is unauthorized(401) just redirect to appropriate action.

```
   protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {                
            // redirected to the login page.
            var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
            if (context.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sending a 302 and a redirect header doesn't really make sense in an ajax context...the ajax client does not automatically follow a redirect. Of course the ajax call could be programmed to look at the Location header and follow it, but if that's what you're advocating you should probably include that side of the code too, and an explanation of what's happening.