# Logout from the session if Selected Item Returns Null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I don't know if this method I'm trying to do is possible to do in asp.net. Just wanted to ask this from experts. :)

In my `HTML` view, I'm reading values from the session and assigning them to the select list item.

So sometimes when the session data is out and the user tries to refresh the Index page, then I got `'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MyBranch`  this error.

So I'm trying to do here to check is this returns null and then I want to redirect to the `Action = Logoff, Controller = Account`.

In my view, this is I tried

```
List<SelectListItem> MyBranch = Session["MyBranch"] as List<SelectListItem>;

        if (MyBranch == null)
        {
            // Need to know here how to redirect this to action
        }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [With ASP.NET MVC redirect to login page when session expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091498/with-asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-expires)

Comment: @SujanRai My code is in the HTML View. Not in the controller. So can't use the ``return RedirectToAction("Logoff", "Account")`` right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<SelectListItem> MyBranch = Session["MyBranch"] as List<SelectListItem>;
if (MyBranch == null) {
    return RedirectToAction("Logoff", "Account") //this will redirect to Logoff action of Account controller
}
```

Comment: My code is in the HTML View. Not in the controller. So cant use the  ``return RedirectToAction("Logoff", "Account")``  right ?

Comment: You need to put this logic in controller section as it is bad practice to put logic in view page too